# how to update value after NSNotificationCenter event happened?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsnotificationcenter

Hi i know this question maybe silly but anyway i ask it now.

i have this function :

```
- (int)getToday {

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fa_IR"];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];
int day = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue];


NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[nc addObserver:self
       selector:@selector(handleSysTimeChanged:)
           name:NSSystemClockDidChangeNotification
         object:nil];



return day;

}
```

and after that i handle notification like this :

```
-(void) handleSysTimeChanged: (NSNotification*) notification
{


if (NSSystemClockDidChangeNotification) {
    NSLog(@"%i", [self getToday]);

}


}
```

and i get exactly the changes i want in my NSLOG. BUT after that how can i update my getToday to show new number after notification happened.
I'm new to objective-c and NSNotificationCenter. So don't be mad.

Comment: You should not be setting up the notification inside the `getToday` method since you most likely call that method more than once. You only want to setup the notification once. And use `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents` instead of using `NSDateFormatter` to get the current day.

Comment: I didn't get your point. i once put notification in my `ApplicationDidFinishLaunching` and handled it in `AppDelegate` and get same result but i don't know how to changed the value in my `getToday`. By the way `NSDateFormatter` is fine for my testing for now.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as @rmaddy said, you should not observe for notifications inside of `getToday`.  This code here is the problem:

```
[nc addObserver:self
       selector:@selector(handleSysTimeChanged:)
           name:NSSystemClockDidChangeNotification
         object:nil];
```

You only want to set up your observer once and if you call `getToday` on each notification, it's going to be called a ton of times. Repetitive `addObserver` calls CAN break things.  Set this up inside of `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` or your class's initialization method.  Also, don't forget to call `removeObserver` before your application terminates or you'll get some really weird errors.

Secondly, I don't think what you're doing is broken.  Based on your provided code, you're getting the **current** date with `[NSDate date]` each time that the notification is received.  This should provide you with the correct day as desired.

Comment: Thanks @taylorc93, i changed the location of my `NC` but the biggest problem i have is how can i change the value that `getToday` return or how i updated the label which currently shown the value of `getToday`.